# For $X$, a normal with mean $0$, variance $1$, find $P[X > 0]$ by using calculus.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

> For $X$, a normal with mean $0$, variance $1$, find $P[X > 0]$ by using calculus.

Got this problem on my probability review and not really sure what "calculus". I'll need to figure this out. Not really sure where to go with this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does not require any calculus, the distribution is continuous and symmetric about $0$.   Perhaps they are asking you to verify the answer by computing the integral?

Comment: You should consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

It wants you to integrate
$$\int_{0}^\infty \phi(x)\,dx$$
where $\phi$ is the density of a standard normal distribution. You might be allow to use facts about the Gaussian integral, or you might be expected to use polar coordinates. Since $0$ is the median, we know the answer is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it means by integrating the density.  Since "calculus" doesn't provide an elementary antiderivative, you use symmetry.